# Javascript Display following wednesday if after 5pm on saturday

Tags: javascript, date

How do I check the current date and if its before 5pm on saturday then display the upcoming Wednesday. However if its after 5pm then display the wednesday of the following week in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This shall do (untested):

```
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var day = date.getDay();
var yourdate = new Date();
if(day==6 && hours >=17)
{
  yourdate.setDate(date.getDate() + 11); 
}
else if (day==6 && hours <17)
{
  yourdate.setDate(date.getDate() + 4); 
}
else if (day==5)
{
  yourdate.setDate(date.getDate() + 5); 
}
else if (day==4)
{
  yourdate.setDate(date.getDate() + 6); 
}
else if (day==3)
{
  yourdate.setDate(date.getDate() + 7); 
}
else if (day==2)
{
  yourdate.setDate(date.getDate() + 8); 
}
else if (day==1)
{
  yourdate.setDate(date.getDate() + 9); 
}
else if (day==0)
{
  yourdate.setDate(date.getDate() + 10); 
}
```

Comment: This will never work on a Sunday.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp clearly states that Sunday will return a 0.

Comment: @Bigalow—please don't reference w3schools, it's not an authority or even very good. Far better to reference [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.getday) for normative references or [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) for examples.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the feedback, I'll keep it in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var nextWednesday = new Date();

if(now.getDay() == 6 && now.getHours() >= 17){
  nextWednesday.setDate(now.getDate() + 11);
}else{
  nextWednesday.setDate(now.getDate() + (10 - now.getDay()));
}
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e1mLo1rv/

If today is saturday and if it is 5pm or later add 11 days to get the desired wednesday. In other ocations you can add 10 days minus the day number to get the needed wednesday.

Thurdays and Fridays and saturdays before 5pm will get you today + 10 - 6, 5 or 4 days wich gets you the upcoming Wednesday.

Sundays, Mondays, Tuesdays and Wednesday will get you today + 10 - 0, 1,2 or 3 days. Thus you will get the next wednesday of the following week.

Can I point out that it is custom on Stackoverflow to first write something yourself, if that fails to post your code and than let the community help you.

Comment: Thank you @Bigalow. That works well. How would you create a countdown to that date and time as well? EX: if a user were to place your order within the next x time, receive your order by X Wednesday based on the same logic as above?

Comment: @MateoM—you are supposed to write the code, then post here if it doesn't work. This isn't a free code writing site. There are many questions about creating timers and count down, search, read, learn, try something. Then ask.

Comment: @MateoM as RobG stated, You should start a new question. With some example code, if you get stuck the comunity will certainly help you. Please accept this answer as accepted as it resolved your original question.